# How To Dynamically Access Object Property?

Tags: actionscript-3, object-property

I have stored name of a property of an object as a string.  In PHP, if the object were named `$object` and the property variable was named `$key`, it could be accessed with `$object->$key`.  How can I dynamically access properties in ActionScript?

Comment: Hmm, x[key] or x.key (the second option will not work if x is strongly typed object.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access it like this:

```
var obj = {
    property1: 'this is a property',
    property2: 'this is another property'
}
var key = 'property2';

obj[key]; // 'this is another property'
```

Answer (score 2):

you can access values and properties in your object either by the dot operator or the array access operator:

```
var myObject:Object = new Object();
myObject.propString = "I'm a String";
myObject.propNumber = 22;
myObject.propObject = {keyOne: "Key String", keyTwo: 23};

trace(myObject["propString"], myObject.propNumber);  //I'm a String 22
trace(myObject.propObject.keyOne, myObject.propObject["keyTwo"]); //Key String 23
```

the above *myObject* variable could also be written like this:

```
var myObject:Object = {propString: "I'm a String", propNumber: 22, propObject: {keyOne: "Key String", keyTwo: 23}};
```